# Logo is missing in Firefox in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My site is showing logo in Chrome but its not visible on Firefox.

My site is at http://nausal.com/test/.

Here is code of my logo image in `header.php`:

```
 <div class="logo">
<h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/\wp-content\themes\avatar\images/logo.png" title="Return to Home." alt="IMAGE TEXT."/></a></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use slashes `/` instead of backslashes `\` in your image path:

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-content/themes/avatar/images/logo.png" title="Return to Home." alt="IMAGE TEXT."/></a></h1>
```